# how to select all cases containing a specific number in spss

Tags: spss

can someone help me figure out how to select cases containing number 1, for example I coded nausea as side effect as 1 and was then noting it with other side effects as 1234 and now i wan to select all combinations with 1 but i cant figure out how. Or at least how to properly name what I am trying to achieve, since I am fairly new to spss so I can try to further search online.

I have tried variable = 1 and variable = *1* and neither worked and a few random commands that did not work either. I have put the variable as string and did not change anything either.

Answer (score 1):

Once you change the variable into text you can use text search commands to find "1" within the text, like this for example:

```
compute nausea=(char.index(YourVariable,"1")>0).
```

`char.index` command searches for "1" in `YourVariable` - if it is there, it will output it's position in the text. If it isn't there, the output is 0. So `nausea` will get a value of 1 in all cases that contain "1" and will gat a value of 0 in all cases that don't.

NOTE - if you get as high as 10 in your numbers, this method will fail, as "10" contains "1". In order for any method to work here, you'd need to add a delimiter between the numbers when you record them, e.g. "1,3,8,17,22".